# When is this integral in $\mathbb{R}^n$ finite?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I found this exercise in an exam test given in previous years, I think the program of the course has changed because I don't know how to approach the exercise.

Up to now I have studied from an analysis perspective Manifolds, sequences and series of functions, uniform convergence, Lagrange multipliers and limits in $\mathbb R^n$.

The exercise is to determine for which $\alpha \ge 0$

$$\int_{A^{\alpha}} \frac{1}{\| (x, y, z) \|^2} \, dx \, dy \, dz$$ is $< \infty$ where $A^\alpha = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid 1 \le z \le (x^2 + y^2)^{- \alpha /2}  \}$

I am curious of to how this is solved, if someone wants to be so kind to explain it to me I would be quite happy. There must be some theorems involved that I do not know I imagine.

Comment: What happens if you integrate using cylindrical coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\alpha>0$: For $x^2+y^2> 1$, we would have $1/(x^2+y^2)^\alpha<1$ which would lead to $1\le z<1$, so we can only have $x^2+y^2\le 1$ in $A^\alpha$.   Considering $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\le 1\}$ equal to the unit disc $D$, and putting $r^2=x^2+y^2$, we can write the integral as something like
$$\int_{D} \int_1^{1/r^{\alpha/2}} \frac{dz}{r^2+z^2} \leq \int_{D} \int_1^\infty \frac{dz}{r^2+z^2}\le \int_{D} \int_1^\infty {dz\over z^2}=\pi\int_1^\infty {dz\over z^2}$$
which is finite.

For $\alpha=0$, $A^\alpha$ is the plane $\{z=1\}$.  In $\mathbb{R}^3$ it has Lebesgue measure $0$, so the integral is zero.